# Committing IndexWriter when a segment is flushed

Tags: lucene

I am using Lucene/Solr for my log search tool. Is there a way I can perform a commit operation on my IndexWriter when a particular set of docs is flushed from memory to the disk. My RamBufferSize is 24Mb and MergeFactor is 10.

Or is calling commit in frequent intervals irrespective of the flushes the only way? I wish the autocommit  feature was not deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using the [commitWithin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommitWithin) feature of Solr. This will hand off the commit responsibilities to Solr.

> CommitWithin is a commit strategy introduced in Solr 1.4, which lets
>   the client ask Solr to make sure this  gets committed within a
>   certain time. This leaves the control of when to do the commit to Solr
>   itself, optimizing number of commits to a minimum while still
>   fulfilling the update latency requirements. If I say  (in an XMLUpdateRequestHandler update), that tells
>   Solr to make sure the document gets committed within 10000ms, i.e.
>   10s. I can then continue to add other documents within those 10
>   seconds (possibly with other commitWithin values), and Solr will
>   automatically do a  when the oldest  in the buffer is
>   due.

I use this quite frequently when adding documents to help keep my as close to NRT (near real time) as I can, without the need for issuing commits at frequent intervals.

Comment: Is there a lucene equivalent for this? Since we use lucene for writing and solr for searching.

Comment: I do not think so. I believe this is a feature of Solr. Sorry I missed that you were not referring to Solr directly, but instead directly to Lucene.